# Is casting a C++ reference from unsigned char to double& safe?

Tags: c++, casting, reference

I am trying to implement a "table" of references for setting various code elements by an index lookup. Most of the underlying variables are `double`, but a few are different types like `unsigned char`.

Here is a simplified example:

```
static unsigned char foo = 0;     // Variable to set
static unsigned double bar = 0.0; // Variable to set
...
struct tableEntry {
    double& ref; // Reference to one of the above
    double min;
    double max;
};
struct tableEntry entries[] {
    { bar, 0.0, 1.0 },
    { (double&)foo, 0x0, 0xff },
};
```

When attempting to assign bar via the table, everything is fine.

```
entries[0].ref = 1.0;
```

This results in `entries[0].ref == 1.0`, and `bar == 1.0`, as expected. However, when assigning foo via the table...

```
entries[1].ref = 1.0;
```

This results in a value mismatch somehow, as if the reference is not able to be interpreted correctly, or isn't even referring to the right object. After this assignment, `entries[1].ref == 1`, but `foo == 0`.

Is this undefined behavior by the language, or am I misusing or abusing something? It's possible it is a discrepancy in versions of the standard, as I tested a similar example on repl.it with C++17 and it worked as I was expecting. This is *not* working as expected when compiling with our target compiler using `mex` in MATLAB, using Visual Studio 2017 as the compiler.

Comment: *Most of the underlying variables are double, but a few are different types like unsigned char.* -- That is what `std::variant<double, unsigned_char>` is designed for.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie unfortunately this is within a larger existing codebase, changing the underlying types would be rocking the boat quite a bit. A good recommendation if I have to build up something similar from scratch though.

Comment: *changing the underlying types would be rocking the boat quite a bit.* -- C++ is a strongly typed language.  Maybe you could try to templatize the code on that one data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading an individual `char` as a `double` is undefined behavior as it breaks type aliasing rules, which is what you are doing. Converting from a `char` value to a `double` value using `static_cast<double>` is perfectly normal and defined though.

It is generally possible to reinterpret `double` as `char`, but only in specific scenarios:

> #### Type aliasing
>
> Whenever an attempt is made to read or modify the stored value of an object of type DynamicType through a glvalue of type AliasedType, the behavior is undefined unless one of the following is true:
>
> - [...]
> - AliasedType is `std::byte` (since C++17), `char`, or `unsigned char`: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.

(See [`reinterpret_cast` conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast))

So we are allowed to examine a `double` (DynamicType) as a `char[]` (AliasedType), but not the other way around. Consider the fact that `char` is exactly one byte large and `double` will most likely be 8 bytes large. What is the value of the remaining 7 bytes when reinterpreting references? It is undefined.

Note that when casting references, a C-style cast like `(double&)` is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<double&>`. I recommend using the explicit C++ casts like `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` and `static_cast` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Alas *strict aliasing* applies to references in a similar way to which it applies to pointers.

The behaviour of making use of the reference attained with `(double&)foo` is *undefined*.